# How do I get the nth minus the (n-1)th term from a dataframe in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that is n rows and 1 column. I can do this to find the 2nd row minus the 1st row:

```
> dif = df[2,1] - df[1,1]
```

How do I find `df[n,1] - df[n-1, 1]` for all rows in df?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`head` and `tail` are handy for this...

```
df <- data.frame( a = 1:5 , b = 5:1 )     
tail(df,-1) - head(df,-1)
#  a  b
#2 1 -1
#3 1 -1
#4 1 -1
#5 1 -1
```

This will therefore accomplish what you are after, row by row, for all columns at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

`diff` is also handy for this task

```
> set.seed(1)
> df <- data.frame( a = sample(5) , b = sample(5) )  # some data 
> sapply(df, diff)
      a  b
[1,]  3 -1
[2,] -1 -2
[3,] -1  1
[4,] -2 -2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `filter`  here :

```
filter(df,c(1,-1))
```